# Scylla Installation issue on RHEL and CentOS

Tags: cassandra, rhel, rhel7, scylla

I am following RHEL instillation steps as decribed here
https://www.scylladb.com/download/rhel_rpm/

Created and added bunch of RPM files in my local repo /etc/yum/repos.d/scylla.repo

While installing below errors are coming.

--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3 for package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: /usr/bin/python3
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python-requests
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python34
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libhwloc.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-tools-core-2.1.6-20180701.fadba0b27.el7.noarch (scylla2.16)
           Requires: java-headless
Error: Package: scylla-tools-2.1.6-20180701.fadba0b27.el7.noarch (scylla2.16)
           Requires: scylla-conf
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libcryptopp.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: PyYAML
Error: Package: scylla-tools-core-2.1.6-20180701.fadba0b27.el7.noarch (scylla2.16)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
Error: Package: scylla-jmx-2.1.6-20180701.315934b.el7.noarch (scylla2.16)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python3-pyudev
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libthrift-0.9.1.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python34-PyYAML
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libjsoncpp.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: hwloc
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python-setuptools
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libyaml-cpp.so.0.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python-urwid
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: collectd
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libgnutlsxx.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: gcc-gnat-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (@RHEL7)
           Requires: libgnat = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Removing: libgnat-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (@RHEL7)
               libgnat = 4.8.2-16.el7
               libgnat = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Obsoleted By: scylla-libgcc72-7.2.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
               Not found
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: libprotobuf.so.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: scylla-server-2.1.6-0.20180701.7d2150a05.el7.x86_64 (scylla2.16)
           Requires: scylla-conf
Error: Package: scylla-tools-core-2.1.6-20180701.fadba0b27.el7.noarch (scylla2.16)
           Requires: python-yaml

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are installing a very old Scylla version (2.1 - 3.0.3 just came out)
2. There are dependencies missing. It looks like you might have skipped the installation step that requires you to install the EPEL repo (`yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`)
3. After you have EPEL in place, you also need to enable all 3 of Scylla's repos (after downloading the repo file you should have these in `yum repolist`):

```
scylla-3.0/7/x86_64       Scylla for Centos 7 - x86_64
scylla-generic-3.0/7      Scylla for centos 7 
scylladb-scylla-3rdparty  Copr repo for scylla-3rdparty owned by scylladb
```

You haven't mentioned the OS version you are using, that is also important.

Comment: Yes, the version is quite older but we will upgrade the same but really my experience was very bad with Scylla. very complex procedure as compare to Cassandra. I think, Scylla must work on it. it will quite helpful if available tarball.

Comment: I understand your concern, but this install procedure is actually very simple and is the best practice for a binary package oriented distribution like RHEL/CentOS or Ubuntu. If you follow the procedure exactly, you will have a working database in no time. You skipped a step, and this is why you could not install

Comment: For EPEL installation require internet into server and we don't have so installing offline by the way installed it. Is it possible to install scylla-manager open source in scylla 2.1.1?

Comment: ok, so you needed an offline installation, you should have mentioned that. There is a procedure documented for it on the Scylla website. As for the manager, it is not opensource. And it requires additional online components. Why are you installing 2.1 at all, there is no advantage to using an old version

Comment: By the way, the unreleased ("master") version of Scylla already has a build option to create a self-contained tarball, which wouldn't require you to install anything else on your system to run. However, it would still be better to use an official RPMs from Scylla instead of tarball because those RPMs also set up various system-wide issues (e.g., kernel parameters, logging, interrupts, benchmarking the disk, etc.) to be the way Scylla needs them.